# Sample codes in old iPhone SDK and the latest SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hi I've just installed the new iPhone SDK and noticed that the samples are missing but instead found at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.htmlsection=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code

I still remember the old SDK has samples bundled with it, so does the new SDK contain about the same number of samples compared to the old one or is it lesser? I won't like to delete existing one and reinstall the one SDK to verify it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can it be that you first have to download the new help-files and that this one include also all the sample code? 
usually after installation you have to download it first (xcode makes it automatically or you can start it in xcode - preferences... - documentation - ios 4.1 library) before you have it.
but i am not sure if downloading it will fill the gap, sorry
bye

Answer (score 0):

You can find the samples code in the iOS Dev Center. There should be a link in the home page right after you sign in. This includes iPad samples. You can sort them by topic, framework or date. There is also a text search.
in /Developer/Examples/iPhone there is a text file that contains the following:

*README
Sample code and example applications for the iPhone SDK are available as part of the iPhone Reference Library. You can find them in Xcode in the Documentation window, or online at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/.*

Apple's iOS Developer samples are also included in Apple's Developer Documentation, the best way to use these samples is to open the Developer Documentation in Xcode and navigate to the sample. You can then browse the sample source code and documentation or open the sample directly from there.
see this [blog post](http://ioscodesamples.blogspot.com/2011/01/ios-code-samples-anyway-you-want-it.html).